# Show that, for all $k=1,2,...$, $||x^{(k)} -x^*|| \leq ||P||^k ||x^0-x^*||$.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrix-equations

> Let $P \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$, $|| P ||<1$, where $||\cdot||$ is a
> consistent norm, $c \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Consider the sequence $\{ x^{(k)}\}_{0}^{\infty}$ given by $x^{(k)}=Px^{(k-1)}+c$ and suppose
> $x^*$ such that $x^*=Px^*+c$. Show that, for all $k=1,2,...$,
> $||x^{(k)} -x^*|| \leq ||P||^k ||x^0-x^*||$.

As exists a consistent norm such that $||P||<1$ then $\rho(P)<1$ ($\rho(P)$ is the "spectral radius of $P$"), so the sequence $\{x^{(k)}\}$ converges to $x^*$, that is $\lim||x^{(k)}-x^*||=0$. By definition, $\forall \varepsilon>0$, exists $k_0$ such that if $k \geq k_0$, then $||x^{(k)}-x^*||<\varepsilon$. This proves for $k \geq k_0$, what about $k=1,2,...,k_0-1$?

Comment: Note that if you prove it for $k = 1$, then the statement follows by induction. So, what can we do for that case?

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't know. If $k=1$ we have $|| x^1 - x^* ||=|| Px^0 + c - x^* ||$, which doesn't seem to tell much story.

Comment: That's a good start. Now use the condition on $x^*$. $\quad$ Highlight to review hint: $\color{white} {x^1 - x^* = (Px + c) - (Px^* + c)  = P(x - x^*)}$.

Comment: I completely forgot I could do that. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i can only consider the situation of $P\in \mathbb{R},c\in \mathbb{R}$

we can find that $x^{(k)}=P^kx_0+\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}cP^j=P^kx_0+c{1-P^k\over 1-P}=P^k(x_0-{c\over 1-P})+{c\over 1-P}$
then for $x^*=Px^*+c$ we got $x^*={c\over 1-P}$
so that  $x^{(k)}=P^k(x_0-x^*)+x^*$

finally $||x^{(k)}-x^*||=||P^k(x_0-x^*)||\leq||P||^k||x_0-x^*||$

by the way,consider $||P||\leq 1$,then $\lim_{k\to\infty}x^{(k)}-x^*=\lim_{k\to\infty}P^k(x_0-x^*)=0$

i hope it would help